# Smfony2: Getting an error when trying to use translatble behavior extension

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to use translatable behavior in my project, I followed the doc word by word to how configure and use this behavior , but I am getting this error:

> CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception ReflectionException: "Property locale does not exist" at C:\wamp\www\Symfony\vendor\gedmo\doctrine-extensions\lib\Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener.php line 296

Can anyone help please?
Thanks in advance :)

Edit:
This is the line 296:

```
$reflectionProperty = $class->getProperty(self::$configurations[$this->name][$meta->name]['locale']);
```

Comment: Did you turn on translations in `config.yml`?

Comment: try to `var_dump` `self::$configurations`.

Comment: And off course you have `$locale;` property in your translatable class?

Answer (score 2):

In my case the required `$locale` field was defined in an abstract super class of the entity - which is basically fine, however it must not be `private` but at most `protected`.